# How to read-write json file without disturbing the sequences of its key-value pairs in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization, jsonserializer

I am serializing a json file whose key-value pairs should not be shuffled when writing to a new file after editing. Even if I do not edit it still goes shuffles the pairs.

I just need the same sequence of the key-value pairs in the new file(written file) as it was in the previous file that I read.

Here is the sample json

```
[
 {
  "StudentName":"Amit",
  "StudentId":"1" 
 },
 {
 "StudentName":"Lalit",
 "StudentId":"2"
 },
 {
 "StudentName":"Ram",
 "StudentId":"3"
 },
 {
 "StudentName":"Shyam",
 "StudentId":"4"
 }
]
```

What I am getting after writing the jsonObject to a new file is:

```
[
  { 
  "StudentName":"Lalit",
  "StudentId":"2"
  },
  {
  "StudentName":"Ram",
  "StudentId":"3"
  },
 {
  "StudentName":"Shyam",
  "StudentId":"4"
 },
 {
  "StudentName":"Amit",
  "StudentId":"1"
 }
]
```

I have two code files, since I am working on command line tool.

1)main.swift

```
  import Foundation

  var behavioralJsonObject : AnyObject
  var newBehavioralDataObject: NSData = NSData()

  let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
  var path = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first
  var stringPath: String = (path?.path)!

  var behavioralFilePath: String = stringPath.stringByAppendingString("/BehavioralFile.json")
  var newBehavioralFilePath : String = stringPath.stringByAppendingString("/BehavioralFileNew.json")


  behavioralJsonObject = MyJsonParser().jsonObject(withFilePath: behavioralFilePath)

  print(behavioralJsonObject.description)

  newBehavioralDataObject = try  NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(behavioralJsonObject, options: .PrettyPrinted)


   newBehavioralDataObject.writeToFile(newBehavioralFilePath, atomically: true)
```

2) MyJsonParser.swift

```
  import Foundation

  class MyJsonParser: NSObject {

  func jsonObject(withFilePath path:String)-> AnyObject{
    let dataObject = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: path)
    var jsonObject: AnyObject = []
    do{
    jsonObject  = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: .AllowFragments)
    }
    catch{
        print("Serialization error : \(error)")
    }
    return jsonObject;
  }

}
```

Has anybody already faced this problem or has a solution for this?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: What does "print(jsonObject.dynamicType" in the "jsonObject(withFilePath path:String)" method show? Just making sure you are reading in an array not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check your code. If your code is correct, you are parsing a JSON array, converting it back to data, and don't write the array elements in the correct order. If that is what really happens, then the only thing you can do is send a bug report to Apple and let them fix it. Array elements have a defined order; if that is changed by the act of reading and writing the array then there is a serious bug somewhere.

It's different with dictionaries. The key/value pairs in a dictionary are unordered. You can't find out in which order they were parsed, and the order in which they are written is undefined. So if your first array element was written as

```
{
   "StudentId":"1" 
   "StudentName":"Amit",
},
```

that would be totally to be expected and completely correct. Changing the order of array elements however is a bug. Note that if you actually read a dictionary and printed out the array of values of the dictionary, that would again be in undefined order.

Comment: Can't I get dictionaries non-shuffled Anyways?

Comment: If you are dependent on the order of the keys inside of an object then you are not using JSON properly, as it does not guarantee any order (it is specifically unordered collection in the spec).

Comment: Actually I have a json which contains about more than 3000 entries(nested), with a proper standard, and that standard needs to be maintained.

Comment: The standard for JSON is that the keys inside of an object (in your case StudentName and StudentId) do not have a determined order. The order that the objects appear within the array has to be maintained however (so Amit comes right before Lalit).